# "Opportunity" and "Chance"

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between *opportunity* and *chance*?
How do I use them?

I always use *opportunity*. As I know, *opportunity* is an occasion to do anything or an occasion which appropriate to do something. *Chance* is an occasion which gets one of two results: gain or lose something. Is this exact?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131543/opportunity-vs-chance

Comment: What do the dictionaries tell you?

Comment: "A *chance* encounter on a beach can be a wonderful *opportunity* to start a beautiful friendship."

Answer (score 2):

One definition of "chance" does mean "opportunity":

> Last week I got the chance to meet my favorite movie star  / Last week I got the opportunity to meet my favorite movie star.
>
> He has a chance to win a medal in the next Olympics / He has an opportunity to win a medal in the next Olympics.

Both of these examples mean more or less the same thing; however because of the broader definition of *chance* there is a nuance of random possibility.  A *chance* to win a medal implies luck is a factor, while an *opportunity* to win a medal just means, as you say, an occasion.

You can change the meaning by using *the* instead of *a*:

> I had the chance / the opportunity to see dolphins when I last went to the beach. (I saw dolphins)
>
> I had a chance / an opportunity to see dolphins when I last went to at the beach. (I could have seen dolphins, but didn't)

Of course "chance" has other definitions where you can't swap in "opportunity":

> They say poker is a game of skill not chance.
>
> Is there any chance you could buy some eggs while you are at the supermarket?
>
> I had a chance meeting with my boss at the baseball game.

Comment: To me, poker is always a game of opportunity, in apposition to bridge, which is a blood sport.

Answer (score 1):

Both words can mean "a situation or event where doing something will benefit you."

*Opportunities* are usually planned or known.  *Chances* are usually unplanned or random.